# Is there an implemented color coin demo for bitcoin?

Tags: colored-coins

Is there an implementation of color coins on the bitcoin blockchain yet? a demo would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Probably chromawallet is the more advanced implementation. http://chromawallet.com/

I think people are only using it on testnet for now.